# How to run two pods in exclusive nodes?

Tags: kubernetes

I'd like to run two pods in exclusive nodes. For instance, I have 4 nodes (node-1, node-2, node-3, node-4) and 2 pods (pod-1, pod-2). I want only one pod to run in each node and each pod to run in two nodes, e.g. pod-1 in node-1 and node-2, pod-2 in node-3 and node-4. Is there a way to configure this way?

Comment: This would defeat the purpose of something like kubernetes. Kubernetes is supposed to run your containers in a way that you don't care where they're actually running, just that they are running.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, Christian. Although I would like to manage node assignment based on node's resource, Kubernetes currently seems not so intelligent...

Comment: Yeah, unfortunately, Kubernetes' scheduler isn't that smart yet.  For something that'll handle that, you'll want to look into things like mesos, which some people have tried using with kubernetes.  Mesos takes a lot more into account when scheduling things on the cluster.

Comment: I also considered using Docker on Mesos (on CoreOS). But it looked too immature and slightly too heavy for my 4-8 nodes use case.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can force exclusivity by creating pod definitions that are unable to schedule on the same machine. The easiest way to do that is to assign each pod the same host port. Once you have the same host port set for both of your pod definitions, if you create two replication controllers with two replicas each, then the scheduler will run 2 copies of 2 pods spread across 4 machines.

Answer (score 2):

What I exactly wanted to do is compassable via [node selection](http://kubernetes.io/docs/user-guide/node-selection/).

Answer (score 2):

Use a [DaemonSet](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/daemonset/#running-pods-on-only-some-nodes) with [Node Affinity](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/configuration/assign-pod-node/) or even [Anti-Affinity](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/configuration/assign-pod-node/#inter-pod-affinity-and-anti-affinity-beta-feature).

Answer (score 1):

You can also use a headless service - it won't guarantee execlusivity, but the algorithm will prefer it during scheduling.

Comment: Thanks, Clayton. Can a headless service's IP be resolved using DNS as non-headless services can?

Comment: If you ask for the A records for a headless service you'll get one A record for each pod (headless has no clusterIP).  I *think* we made the change so that SRV records for a regular service would include A records for each pod, but maybe not.  If you choose headless services, you also won't get an env var (although there's a bug open for it and we plan to fix it one way or another).

Comment: Also, regular services also prefer spread the same way if you have that predicate configured - I only suggested headless services if you don't want to force a cluster ip

Comment: https://docs.openshift.org/latest/admin_guide/scheduler.html#use-cases contains an example of turning on the service spread priority

Comment: Thanks. I'll try to use A record till I need variable ports. Also I'm going to dive into scheduler.