# Deploy Kubernetes pods on unique nodes

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-pod

Is there a way to deploy a replica set in Kubernetes on unique nodes?

All the documentation I can find on Kubernetes NodeSelectors, (anti-)affinity, etc., seems to relate to specifying a particular node you do or don't want the pods to be on. I don't mind which nodes my pods are on, I just don't want two pods from a deployment on the same one-- I want to spread them out.

It seems like a simple enough thing to do-- in Mesos you can apply a constraint like "HOSTNAME: unique" to achieve it-- but I can't find the Kubernetes equivalent. Can anyone help, please?

Comment: Daemonset? https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/daemonset/

Comment: [Possible duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30976377/how-to-run-two-pods-in-exclusive-nodes), check first answer.

Comment: Thanks, I did check, but you're right- it's a duplicate question.

Comment: I think first answer is correct with pod anti-affinity. First answer of the possible duplicate seems overly complicated.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to run two pods in exclusive nodes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30976377/how-to-run-two-pods-in-exclusive-nodes)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In contrast with the first answer described in the comments below your question I'd say the right approach is to define `pod anti-affinity` as described [in the docs](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/configuration/assign-pod-node/#inter-pod-affinity-and-anti-affinity-beta-feature). More precisely:

> The rules are of the form “this pod should (or, in the case of anti-affinity, should not) run in an X if that X is already running one or more pods that meet rule Y”.

Feel free to share your scenario details in order to propose a solution. Of course, if you want to run your deployment on compute plane exclusively or compute + control plane you'd choose `Deployment` resp. `DaemonSet` in case of the latter.

Comment: I never followed up on this thread, but with a couple years more Kubernetes experience under my belt, I know that pod anti-affinity would have been the solution. Setting `spec.affinity.podAntiAffinity.requiredDuringSchedulingIgnoredDuringExecution.podAffinityTerm` to something that matches the pod's own labels would mean that it wouldn't launch a second pod from the same deployment on the same node.